# setPTS outputting wrong duration (Ffmpeg)

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I have a video of duration 14 seconds. I applied the setPTS filter to make it 3 times slow. So the total duration should be 42s (14*3). But the output gives a 49s long video. Here is the command:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=3*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=0.6,atempo=0.5[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

What is wrong with this command? I tried it for different videos but all has the same weird issue. Any help will be appreciated. Regards.

Log:

```
ffmpeg version git-2020-08-31-4a11a6f Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.1 (GCC) 20200805
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libgsm --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 58.100 / 56. 58.100
  libavcodec     58.101.101 / 58.101.101
  libavformat    58. 51.101 / 58. 51.101
  libavdevice    58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
  libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2018-11-20T06:28:07.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:14.72, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 688 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, unknown/bt470bg/unknown), 198x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 11:20], 592 kb/s, 29.93 fps, 29.93 tbr, 29931 tbn, 59.86 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-11-20T06:28:07.000000Z
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
File 'output.mp4' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> setpts
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> atempo
  setpts -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  atempo -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0000021e37f15340] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0000021e37f15340] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0000021e37f15340] profile High, level 1.3, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0000021e37f15340] 264 - core 161 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2020 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    encoder         : Lavf58.51.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 198x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 11:20], q=-1--1, 29.93 fps, 29931 tbn, 29.93 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.101.101 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.101.101 aac
frame= 1313 fps=256 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2241kB time=00:00:44.11 bitrate= 416.2kbits/s dup=875 drop=0 speed=8.61x
video:1500kB audio:693kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.182632%
[libx264 @ 0000021e37f15340] frame I:7     Avg QP:21.61  size: 18425
[libx264 @ 0000021e37f15340] frame P:331   Avg QP:24.78  size:  3593
[libx264 @ 0000021e37f15340] frame B:975   Avg QP:31.57  size:   223
[libx264 @ 0000021e37f15340] consecutive B-frames:  0.8%  0.2%  1.6% 97.5%
[libx264 @ 0000021e37f15340] mb I  I16..4:  3.6% 31.1% 65.3%
[libx264 @ 0000021e37f15340] mb P  I16..4:  0.8%  1.3%  4.2%  P16..4: 37.0% 29.0% 15.9%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:11.7%
[libx264 @ 0000021e37f15340] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.2%  B16..8:  8.4%  2.8%  1.2%  direct: 0.4%  skip:87.0%  L0:61.8% L1:31.0% BI: 7.3%
[libx264 @ 0000021e37f15340] 8x8 transform intra:22.3% inter:18.7%
[libx264 @ 0000021e37f15340] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 73.2% 85.7% 52.9% inter: 11.6% 7.4% 0.7%
[libx264 @ 0000021e37f15340] i16 v,h,dc,p: 25% 33% 22% 19%
[libx264 @ 0000021e37f15340] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 20% 28% 19%  4%  5%  4%  7%  5%  7%
[libx264 @ 0000021e37f15340] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 23% 26% 13%  5%  7%  6%  7%  6%  7%
[libx264 @ 0000021e37f15340] i8c dc,h,v,p: 38% 29% 22% 11%
[libx264 @ 0000021e37f15340] Weighted P-Frames: Y:2.7% UV:0.3%
[libx264 @ 0000021e37f15340] ref P L0: 86.1%  8.9%  3.6%  1.4%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0000021e37f15340] ref B L0: 94.7%  4.6%  0.8%
[libx264 @ 0000021e37f15340] ref B L1: 99.3%  0.7%
[libx264 @ 0000021e37f15340] kb/s:280.02
[aac @ 0000021e3847c900] Qavg: 729.586
```

Comment: atempo 0.6 x 0.5 = 0.3 which leads to 3.33x length. `atempo=0.33` is the corresponding value you need.

Comment: but atempo accepts only range between 0.5 - 3.0 ? How to fix this?

Comment: `atempo=0.6666,atempo=0.5`

Comment: Thank you there has been a decrease but the duration is still inacurate. It is now  44s long. The reason why I need precise duration is that users cannot upload a video more than 45s long. So in this case, the video can get more than 45s long during transcode and we need the duration to be same for all videos (under 45 seconds).

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: Shared full log.

Comment: Looks fine. Input duration is 14.72s which times 3 = 44.16s.